# Отправить ajax и получить ответ

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xhr

На странице 1 я выполняю XMLHttpRequest на страницу 2.
На странице 2 находится JS функция load код который выполняет XMLHttpRequest запрос и получает в ответ json.

Не могу собразить как мне выполнить XMLHttpRequest на странице 1 и прочитать ответ запроса от функции load ?

```
function load {
    var str = {
        head: {
            hash: 827635425,
            time: Date.now()
        },
        body: {
            content: {}
        }
    };
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'package.json', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('OK!');
        } else {
            console.log('NO!');
        }
    });
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS функция load выполняется на клиенте, а не на сервере. Когда вы делаете запрос со страницы 1 на страницу 2 вы получаете в ответе в содержимое. У него может быть разный тип, например text/html или application/json в зависимости от того, что возвращает сервер.
Вам нужно разместить аналог функции load на сервере и делать запрос на этот хэндлер.

Comment: Страницу 2 не хотелось бы редактировать. Ибо поломается всё. Не подскажите какие есть ещё варианты ? Есть мысль страницу 2 открыть в `iframe` но как получить ответ от функции load не могу сообразить.